Is it possible to check Core Web Vitals for only your main domain, excluding the subdomain?
I'm trying to check the core web vitals of my website but found out that it also checked my subdomains. I've checked PageSpeed Insights and GSC but couldn't find ways to deal with this.
How can I avoid that?

SEO tuning is not really a programming issue. I wonder if there are going to be better places to ask this.
